# Tensorflow android demo issue using bazel "cannot find symbol class Fill where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class Zeros"

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, bazel

I am going to build Tensorflow Object Detection API Android demo using Bazel which is def nativeBuildSystem = 'bazel' in Android Studio, but got the following error:
**error: cannot find symbol class Fill where T is a type-variable: T extends Object declared in class Zeros**. Comments in other repositories claim that native builder should be set to *none*, in order to solve this issue, however, it is stated instructions in Tensorflow Android Camera Demo that demo can be built using Bazel and Android Studio.

System information:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
TensorFlow installed from source.
TensorFlow version 1.12.
Python version 2.7.
Bazel version 0.21.0.
Android Studio Version: 3.3
Gradle version: 3.3.0
```

Any of suggestions and comments in other repositories and forums related to this issue did not help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing research on this topic, and discussing the problem in other repositories (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25239), I made following conclusions:

- As mentioned in the TensorFlow Dev Summit, TensorFlow Mobile is being deprecated. It's highly unlikely that they'll continue supporting the gradle-based builds for the TFMobile samples.
- That said, it looks like this is an issue with the codegen dependency, as the Fill class is dynamically generated. Maybe there have been some more recent changes in how these classes are generated.
- Thus, instead of using Tensorflow Mobile it is recommended to us TFLite